# What kind of Bottom Bracket is this? And what is broken?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have a MTB that I haven't been using from a while. Recently I thought of going for a ride but I remembered that it had something broken inside the BB ! So I was thinking what kind of BB it was ? And how could I repair it ? Actually it broke when I was riding my cycle very fast and suddenly the bottom bracket got undo you know...... Then I tried to tighten it temporarily tighten it So that I could take it to the mechanic afterwards. After some days I took it to him. He said something was broken inside and he would repair it. But after a few days it started to make noise then the pedals were not being straight while riding you know a bit wobbly and cross.. Then I left it for some days till now......

[image]

**Update:** After I checked the [datasheet or the manual of the Shimano derailleur](http://fish.shimano-eu.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Tourney/SL-TY18/SI-6D80B-Eng_v1_m56577569830689295.pdf) it says best results with a BB-TY30 Then according to that it may have a bb-ty30. But after a bit of searching I found this picture that looks similar.......to mine. And I will source the real images as fast as possible.....

[image]

**Here are the links**
[LINK 1](https://m.compareraja.in/hero-octane-dtb-26t-bicycle-price.html)
[LINK 2](http://www.gaadi.com/cycles/model-specifications-hero_octane_dtb_26t)

Comment: You need better pictures to even tell what kind of crankset is on there.

Comment: Can't tell much from that lousy picture.  It *appears* to be a 3-piece crank,  but can't be sure.  And there are a half-dozen different variations on 3-piece cranks.  Probably 80% of recent units are simple cartridge units, but still can't guess what sort of end is on the crank -- whether square or one of the splined schemes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a bicycle. If you want more specific info, you'll have to take some pictures of the BB.

Comment: You can find better photos by googling the model name. The problem is, they are different, some seem to have cottered steel cranks and others some kind of three piece crank.

Comment: @ojs - Yeah, in some pictures that does look amazingly like a cottered crank, which is incredible for a bike presumably built in this century.

Comment: The weirdest thing is that it's a mountain triple, something that didn't even exist when cottered cranks were popular. So this can't be just an old stock the manufacturer bought cheap.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak my guess is bicycle shaped object.

Comment: It is a bicycle from a 3rd world country. So, its hard tosay whats there. But I'd venture that if its a 3 piece crank, it is a square taper. The rest of the bike s not spec'd high enough to do annything fancier.

Comment: Sorry for the resources I will try my best to give you all the pictures..... Sorry again....

Comment: [This](http://www.mytenspeeds.com/My_TenSpeeds_1/Bicycles_Table/English_Bicycles/Falcon_Bicycles/Falcon_Blue_57/FalconBlue_57_Cranks_1.jpg) is a cottered crank.  Note that there is a bolt (the "cotter pin") running crossways through the crank, near the shaft.  Also note that the crank is pretty skinny (because it's typically steel rather than aluminum).  If this is what you have then the whole thing probably needs to be replaced with a more modern design (but finding a replacement that fits is apt to be difficult).

Answer (score 1):

If those links are exactly your bike, then it looks like a MTB BSO with utterly standard components.  26" wheels with V brakes and a 7 speed freewheel on the back is nothing special.

Your other image shows and english threadded bottom bracket cartridge with square taper interface to the cranks.  That will likely fit 2/3 of the MTB bikes and about 99% of the BSO grade MTBs.

The only other option is likely to be a cup-and-cone bearing bottom bracket, and we could tell that by looking at a photo of the bike's BB area, as requested already.

Neither of these two BB setups is weird or rare.